# How to convert a primary partition to logical?

Tags: windows-8, partitioning

I am using Windows 8 and I partitioned hard disk into separate drives using disk management. The problem is that the new partitions created are shown as primary partitions. How do I change them to logical?

Answer (score 6):

Very few partition managers can perform this task. [EaseUS Partition Master Home Edition](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm) is one of those few ([source](http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/comparison.html)), and it's freeware.

Performing the conversion is straightforward:

[image: screenshot]

Keep in mind that any change to an existing partition implies a certain risk of data loss.

Comment: I tried using Ease us. When I installed and right clicked as it is shown in the screenshot given by you there is not convert to logical option. Whereas the same software when installed in my friend's laptop who is having windows7 the option is shown.

Comment: Does it show up for any of the partitions? According to [this](http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/help/convert-primary-to-logical.htm), you cannot convert the partitions with status *System* or *Boot*.

Comment: No it is not showing for any partition

Comment: That's odd; Windows 8 is supposed to be supported. Here's another tool that promises this feature: [Partition Assistant](www.disk-partition.com/help/convert-primary-to-logical.html) (I don't have used this one myself.) If that doesn't work either, do you have by any chance an external enclosure or a USB to SATA adapter to connect your HDD to your friend's laptop?

Comment: A large number of these softwares will only do this conversion with the full version, and it is disabled in the free version. I've seen this specifically with EaseUS. I will look into the other ones, but I've gone through several, and they all have the same business model so far. EDIT: your URL goes to AOMEI, I've tried their version, and it does the same thing, except it doesn't even list the option in freeware. This is very specifically a thing it charges for with the full edition.

Answer (score 2):

If the computer came with Windows 8 pre-installed, it almost certainly uses UEFI and the [GUID Partition Table (GPT),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) rather than the older [Master Boot Record (MBR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partitioning system. GPT doesn't include the distinction between primary, extended, and logical partitions; in GPT, you've just got partitions, which are most similar to MBR primary partitions. Windows reports all GPT partitions as being "primary." A default GPT supports up to 128 partitions, and this value can be raised in a few partitioning tools, if necessary. If you're using GPT, that would explain why EaseUS gives you no option to convert a partition to logical: It's impossible under GPT!

You can check your partition table type as follows (although these instructions are for Windows 7; it may be different in Windows 8):

1. Open the Control Panel.
2. Click System and Security.
3. Click Create and Format Hard Disk Partitions under Administrative Tools. The Disk Management window should open.
4. Right-click on Disk 0 (or whatever disk you want to check) on the left side of the bottom pane of the window. A context menu should appear.
5. Click Properties in the context menu. A Properties dialog box should open.
6. Select the Volumes tab. The result should resemble the below figure. The Partition Style item identifies the partition table type—GPT in this example.

[image: Partition table type is shown here.]

If your disk really is an MBR disk, then my [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) utility can do primary-to-logical conversions, with some caveats and limitations. Most notably, you must have at least one free sector immediately preceding each to-be-logical partition. This may require resizing or moving some partitions. (Shrinking the preceding partition from its end is likely to be both faster and quicker than moving the start point of the to-be-logical partition.)

Comment: Yes what you said is correct. The partition type is shown as GPT. The boot is in UEFI mode. So, how do I now install ubuntu in my system with a dual boot.

Comment: Your follow-on question is *extremely* open-ended. Follow the various guides for installing Ubuntu. I don't have URLs handy, but I know there's plenty of documentation that covers EFI-based installations. If you have problems, try posting a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

It is the processes which without recovering any data, you can recover your HDD partition primary to logical and dynamic to logical or after using Ubuntu you can get back your drive like when you purchased!

By using the following Steps:

1. Insert Windows 7 or 8 DVD or  Bootable pen drive.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>. (For Open CMD.EXE with Administrative Privileges.)
3. Type following commands one by one and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   ```
   DISKPART

   LIST DISK

   SELECT DISK 0

   CLEAN ALL (Take time may be 1 hr).
   ```

   After successful execution of the `CLEAN ALL` command, by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> key and You click on REFRESH button in the Windows PARTITION window, and PARTITION shows as Unallocated Space and show full HDD space, then go back in `CMD.EXE` by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Then type following commands.

   Type `EXIT` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (2 times).
4. Close  WINDOWS 7 or 8 without doing any partition.
5. Insert Windows XP Cd or Bootable Pen Drive.
6. PARTITION the HDD by using XP.
7. close XP with <kbd>F3</kbd>.
8. Again Insert Windows 7 or 8 DVD or Bootable Pen Drive.
9. Format (without breaking any partition).

Answer (score 1):

So far I've been searching on the internet and I only found advertisement for softwares that you need to buy in order to do such a simple task, the only reliable software that helped me do it in **simple** way and **FREE** is the

[Paragon Partition Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/free/pm-express/)

Answer (score 0):

Well first get an understanding on of partitions and logical drives. The first 3 partitions created are primary partitions. They act and work the same as logical drives. However logical drives can't contain the operating system. So there really is no need to convert them to logical. If you create a 4th partition then it will become an extended partition since there can be only 3 primary partitions, all of which work the same. Here is more info, it says Vista but it should be the same.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-vista/What-are-partitions-and-logical-drives

Comment: I know this. What you said was the case may be till windows7.I have a 1 TB hardrive in my laptop and it cme with two partitions one for the c drive containing the windows8 and other is the lenovo drivers. I created another 3 partitions. It created them and shows all the five partitions as primary. That is the reason why I asked the question.

Comment: But what I was saying there is nothing wrong with it being primary partitions. That is just a designation. It can still hold all the data and anything you want to store. It is no different than you getting another hard drive for data only. It will also be a primary partition. So what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to install ubuntu in my laptop with dual boot option. I was unsuccessful in doing so.  So I thought it might be due to having many primary partitions.